# inner/outer class SCJP

Tags: java, scjp

Which three code fragments, added individually at line 26, produce the output 100? (Choose three.)

```
class Inner {

private int x;

public void setX(int x) {this.x = x;}

public int getX(){return x;}
}

class Outer{

 private Inner y;

 public void setY(Inner y) {this.y = y;}

 public Inner getY(){return y;}

}

public class Gamma {

 public static void main(String[] args){

 Outer o = new Outer();

 Inner i = new Inner();

 int n = 10;

 i.setX(n);

 o.setY(i);

**// Line 26**

 System.out.println(o.getY().getX());

 }

 }
```

This question is from SCJP

```
A.
n = 100;

B.
i.setX( 100 );

C.
o.getY().setX( 100 );

D.
i = new Inner(); i.setX( 100 );

E.
o.setY( i ); 
i = new Inner(); 
i.setX( 100 );

F.
i = new Inner(); 
i.setX( 100 ); 
o.setY( i );
```

ANSWER IS BCF

I understand B and C but i dont understand F.
If i use D option why its giving me 10 as output. I want to know what is happening when i use option D.

Ure replies are more than welcomed

Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you applying these option? there is already created object inside main()..then again you are creating?

Answer (score 0):

The only object that has a `getX` method is `Inner`.   `Outer` exposes a setter to `Inner`, allowing you to set the reference that you want.  The reference being passed in has a `setX` call with the value `100`, hence the reason why it works.

To illustrate it with a bit of ASCII art...

```
Outer     Inner      int
+---+     +---+     +---+
| o | --- | y | --- | x |
+---+     +---+     +---+
```

- You instantiate a reference of `Inner`.
- You set the instance of `Inner`'s int value to 100.
- You place your reference of `Inner` inside of `Outer`.  `Inner`'s int value is still 100.
- You then call `o.getY().getX()`, which retrieves the value of `100`.

Answer (score 0):

On your code at "line 25" the variable i and y refers to the same memory address, so if u take the option D, you will create a new object and i will point to a new memory adress, making any change to i to be independent of the first Inner object created and which variable y is still pointing

:D